# How to stop http request from dash_renderer

Tags: plotly-dash

I am trying a build a realtime monitoring system for high frequency data. To increase the performance, I used the extendData property of dcc.Graph() and websocket. So that, the brouser does not need to send request to get data.
I found that it still not increasing the performance as expected. The reason I found is, from the browser, I see (by inspecting network from browser) after some miliseconds browser is still sendng request and the initiator is the dash_renderer.[image]

This picture is for a vanilla example just to show even for a textbox example the http request goes on and on. And for my real time websocket dashboard the frequency of requests get very high.

My question is:

1. What dash_renderer do?
2. why it is sending http request?
3. **And how to stop that?**

Comment: dash_renderer is what makes Dash work. Stopping it would break Dash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is late, After some experience, my realization is dash is not designed to work with websocket. It uses call-backs which actually sends requests to server and in server, the callback function (which is python) send back some result.
These call-backs are designed to send HTTP request to server.

For high speed data, the websocket should be used with `extendTrace` method of plotly.js in client side.

Answer (score 1):

If you run Dash in Debug mode, it has a feature called *Hot Reloading* which regularly (every 3 seconds by default) checks for changes to your codebase and updates your running app if it finds any. That check for updated code is what you're seeing in the network inspection.

To turn it off, either don't run in debug mode or explicitly set `dev_tools_hot_reload` to False like so:

```
app.run_server(debug=True, dev_tools_hot_reload=False)
```